# How to read custom SOAP header from response using WCF client

Tags: .net, wcf, service, header

So there is my problem: I can't get header from web service response by using generated wcf proxy (service reference) while services are asmx.

```
ManagerSoapClient client = new ManagerSoapClient();
client.Authenticate(...);
using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
{
    //headers = null
    var headers = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders;
}
```

It's strange, because SOAP response has some header:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Header>
      <OperationResult xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <Status>Success</Status>
      </OperationResult>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      ...
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Ok, I added custom `IClientMessageInspector` to check headers:

```
public class OperationResultMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {           
        return channel;
    }

    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        //It founds header at position 0!!
        int headerIndex = reply.Headers.FindHeader("OperationResult", "http://tempuri.org/");
    }
}
```

So there is a header after all... But why I can't access it using `OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders`?

Ok. Now I just want to save this header in some place to be able to access it after service call. I decided to use extensions `IExtension<OperationContext>`
So my code now is next:

```
public class ManagerProxy
{
    public void Authenticate()
    {
        ManagerSoapClient client = new ManagerSoapClient();
        client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new OperationResultBehavior());
        client.Authenticate(...);

        using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
        {
            //headers = null
            var headers = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders;
            //header = null
            OperationResultContextExtension header = OperationContext.Current.Extensions.Find<OperationResultContextExtension>();
        }
    }
}

public class OperationResultMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {           
        return channel;
    }

    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        IClientChannel channel = (IClientChannel)correlationState;

        //It founds header at position 0!!
        int headerIndex = reply.Headers.FindHeader("OperationResult", "http://tempuri.org/");
        XmlDictionaryReader reader = reply.Headers.GetReaderAtHeader(headerIndex);

        OperationResultContextExtension extension = new OperationResultContextExtension
        {
            SomeData = reader.ReadString()
        };          

        using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(channel))
        {               
            OperationContext.Current.Extensions.Add(extension);
        }
        reader.Close();
    }

}

public class OperationResultContextExtension : IExtension<OperationContext>
{
    public string SomeData { get; set; }
    public void Attach(OperationContext owner) { }
    public void Detach(OperationContext owner) { }
}

public class OperationResultBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters) { }
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher) { }
    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint) { }
    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    { clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new OperationResultMessageInspector()); }
}
```

It should work, but unexpectedly for me `OperationContext.Current.Extensions.Find<OperationResultContextExtension>();` is `null` as well.

So there are my questions:
1. Why `OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders` returns `null` while `reply.Headers.FindHeader` found header correctly inside `AfterReceiveReply`
2. Extension `OperationResultContextExtension` looks pretty smooth, why I get `null` during `OperationContext.Current.Extensions.Find<OperationResultContextExtension>()`.
3. Is there some better/simpler or at least working well way to obtain this headers from response?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue to this and in my case I resolved it by putting the client call inside the `OperationContestScope`

```
ManagerSoapClient client = new ManagerSoapClient();

using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
{
    client.Authenticate(...); // <---- The change
    var headers = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders;
}
```

Comment: I tried this approach, however all the fields in the "headers" object are null, even though in Fiddler I can see header fields such as Action, To and From. Any ideas?

Comment: @AntonK found anything working? :) OCT2018 - WCF @ .NET4.5